# Web form to send email not working

Tags: php, html, forms

I only need a very basic/simple form to send the email but it doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why? I know the code isn't very advanced and probably looking 'ugly' but it will do for what I 'need' it for

```
if (isset($_POST['email']))
{

    $full_name = $_POST['fullName'];
    $phone = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
    $adMessage = $_POST['emailMessage'];

    //send email
    $to = "info@lalalalala.co.uk";
    $from = $_POST['emailAddress'];
    $subject = $_POST['emailSubject'];

    $message = "Full name: " . $full_name . "\n";
    $message .= "Phone number: " . $phone . "\n";
    $message .= "Email Address: " . $from . "\n";
    $message .= "Additional Message: " . $adMessage;


    $headers = "From:" . $full_name;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

HTML

```
<form action='' method='post'>

    <fieldset><label id="fullName">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fullName" value="Please Enter Your Full Name" onclick="this.value=''"  /></fieldset>

    <fieldset><label id="emailAddress">Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="emailAddress" value="Please Enter Your Email Address" onclick="this.value=''"  /></fieldset>

    <fieldset><label id="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" value="Please Enter Your Phone Number" onclick="this.value=''"  /></fieldset>

    <fieldset><label id="emailSubject">Email Subject</label>
    <input type="text" name="emailSubject" value="Please Enter Email Subject" onclick="this.value=''"  /></fieldset>

    <fieldset><label id="emailMessage">Your Message</label>
    <textarea cols="10" rows="20" name="emailMessage" onclick="this.value=''" >Please Enter Your Message</textarea></fieldset>

    <fieldset><input type="image" src="images/submit.png" id="submit" onclick="show_alert();" /></fieldset>
</form>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Why does it work ? what errors do you get ? have you tried debugging it ?

Comment: are you trying to send mail from local ??? ;)

Comment: I've got exactly the same form on the other website and it works fine, but for some reason this one won't send the email.

I was trying to send the email from the actual server. I'm a PHP n00b hence I just want to keep it simple and in time 'upgrade' the code :P

Comment: Add an input to the form with the name "email". Was an answer, but it seems to have been removed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set any input named `email`. Your first conditional won't be evaluated to true, so you skip everything that follows.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (isset($_POST['email']))
```

to

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Your form does not have an element named `email` - so it will never enter that `if` block. The replacement checks that the request method was `POST` ie a form was posted.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see any `input field` in your form named **Email** which your are using in your condition i.e.

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])){....}
```

There is a field named **emailAddress**, so use:

```
if (isset($_POST['emailAddress'])){....}
```

Hope this helps.